# Markings after Rehearsal mark

Tags: rehearsal

The question is about writing marking (pedal, Chord symbols, dynamics ...) after Rehersal marks. Is it a good practice to write down Markings after RM again even if it is repetitious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding properly, this would be considered a courtesy marking, much like a courtesy accidental.  The general convention says that if a marking is not contradicted by a new one, then it remains, so it wouldn't be necessary to add these markings but as a courtesy, you can include them to help the player that is reading the piece.  I would avoid doing this too frequently, though, as it would clutter your score if they were placed on every bar (which I understand is not your intention, just hyperbole for an example).  Adding this sort of courtesy marking is actually a great idea for after rehearsal marks, as you will likely use those spots as a starting point during rehearsals, often times not coming directly from the preceding section, so players can avoid having to go back however many measures to try to figure out what dynamic they should be playing at.  So I'd say that it's a good idea to include, just don't go overboard.